Bitmap reference issue: ... is defined in an assembly that is not referenced
Im making a script to compare two images, using the Accord.Imaging package. but i get these errors when i try to use it (this happens multiple times)
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   CS0012  The type 'Bitmap' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'CoreCompat.System.Drawing, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.    Machine learning test   C:\Users\Night\source\repos\Machine learning test\Machine learning test\ImageComparer.cs    9   Active  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   CS0012  The type 'BitmapData' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'CoreCompat.System.Drawing, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.    Machine learning test   C:\Users\Night\source\repos\Machine learning test\Machine learning test\ImageComparer.cs    15  Active  

when I add CoreCompat.System.Drawing (using nuget), I get a bunch more errors from other parts of my code
public static float CompareImages(Bitmap image1, Bitmap image2)
{
    UnmanagedImage img1 = UnmanagedImage.FromManagedImage(image1);
    UnmanagedImage img2 = UnmanagedImage.FromManagedImage(image2);
    // Create a new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching
    Accord.Imaging.ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new Accord.Imaging.ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0.9f);

    // Compare
    Accord.Imaging.TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage(img1, img2);

    // Check the similarity level
    if (matchings.Length > 0)
    {
        return matchings[0].Similarity;
    }

    return 0;
}


I think "CoreCompat.System.Drawing" is a redirected assembly, and that you should be referencing system.drawing.common. You should probably also state the .net version you are targeting, as well as your current references. Note that Accord is like 7 years old, so it might have some compatibility issues with later .net versions. I would consider using some maintained library instead.
